# AWS Mobile hub with Cocoa pods Apple Mach-O Linker error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, amazon-web-services

I generated a AWS Mobile hub iOS Swift application and tried to add Google Maps SDK using Cocoapods but after doing that It generates this Error

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K1eX.png)

After searching several times I deleted the -ObjC linker flag and just added -force_load then it started giving Missing File or Directory error. How can I fix this.

I'm running on XCode 8.2, AWS Mobile hub project is Swift 2.3

PS: I tried adding use_frameworks! in Podfile.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the -ObjC flag, you need to use the -force_load flag specifically for the Google Maps SDK. if you use the -ObjC flag, it will require all libraries to be force loaded even if they are not used in your app.

Thanks,
Rohan